# Figuring out the Ligatures/Kernings of a Font

Tags: fonts, typography, page-layout, measurement, ligatures

There are ways to measure text in the browser, taking into account the font size. However, you could get a performance improvement if you only measure the different characters, and then you combine the characters into words. For example, measure the letters `f` and `o`, and then use the measurements to compute the measurement of `foo`. The problem is, `foo` is not equal to `f + o + o` (in the browser), as seen here:

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas')
var s = c.getContext('2d')
c.font = '400 normal 12px Arial'
var a = s.measureText('f').width
var b = s.measureText('o').width
var x = a + b + b
var y = s.measureText('foo').width
console.log(x) //=> 14.0662841796875
console.log(y) //=> 14.143630981445312
```

So basically:

```
f + o + o = 14.07
foo       = 14.14
```

So `foo` is slightly longer than `f + o + o`. I am wondering if there is any way to figure this out in advance. That is, for a given font, if there is a way to know, when letters are combined, what the final size will be, without just measuring the whole string of text as one chunk.

I think this is because of ligatures or kerning which I am not too familiar with. But maybe there is a way to get a list of all the ligatures/kernings for a particular font, which will tell you the ratio of "compression" or "space" it removes or adds to letters in certain combinations.

Wondering if anything like this exists, or if it is at all possible. Not exactly sure I am pinpointing the problem (i.e. that it is related to kerning/ligatures), but assuming it is the problem, wondering how to get a list of the ligatures/kerning for a font, so I can do the measurements in advance. Maybe it is somehow encoded in the font eot or ttf or related files, or maybe there is a list on some website. If it's not the problem, then wondering what the problem is and how one might get the data to solve it.

Comment: Why are you asking a programming question on a forum for people who dont generally program? But yes this info is in the font file. Its just that the width of the character might differ form yours. See opentype.js or Typr.js

Comment: The question isn't about programming it's about where to get this measurement info. The programming part just demonstrates what the problem is.

Comment: Well getting this info is either a programming task or you can just use a font editor to get this info and calculate it yourself.  Either way you wont be doing this manually as its packed in a binary container

Comment: Good point, thank you. I will switch this over to stack overflow.

Comment: also its potentially also quite hard to guess exactly in pixels as its also possibly hinted.

Comment: "Maybe it is somehow encoded in the font": scratch the 'maybe', of course it is. But reading out those tables falls under *very* advanced programming, and if your question on Stack Overflow will come down to 'so how do I do this' it will be closed as "too broad".

Comment: While I would consider this question on-topic as per our [scope consensus for code questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3311), problems that were hinted to arise on [so] are also problems here, namely the question is too broad. Please narrow it down by specifying your situation a bit more: 1) What are your constraints in terms of efficiency, memory, and similar. 2) Are you restricted to a certain platform or similar? — Alternatively, a question that would certainly be suited for this site is to ask for what kind of font features can affect this.